# Error on external login with facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth-2.0

The past 2 days I'm struggling to fix the error I'm getting when I try to login to my site using Facebook authentication.

The error I'm getting:

[image]

How can I find what causing this problem? I debugged my code and didn't find any errors. (The code worked until 2 days ago)

The code I'm using:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         var FacebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
                {
                AppId = "**************",
                AppSecret = "***************************",
                BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
                Scope = { "email" },
                UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?fields=id,name,email"
         };
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(FacebookOptions);
    }
}
public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
            {
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
            }
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added your domain to the application configuration?  I'm pretty sure that not having the right URL in there can cause this error.

Comment: Yes! And it worked until 2 days ago!